# How to implement Sandboxie

Tags: winapi, shell, kernel

As I saw Sandboxie makes a virtual space on hard disk and there are allowed the programs to write.

[image: Sandboxie Demo]

This how can be implemented as software?
Which windows (kernel,shell ?) functions needed to be overriden?

Comment: It is *very* hard to take some kind of product seriously that sounds like a poodle mishap.  Naming is *so* important, automatic -100 points when you get that wrong.  Isolated storage is *well* supported in Win32.

Answer (score 4):

Software like Sandboxie basically provide a virtual execution environment for (sandboxed) applications. They do this by virualizing file system and Registry (read/write/delete/exec operations) among other things. They are also called feather-weight virtual machines, as they provide a virtual machine like environment for individual applications. You can refer to these pages for more info:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fvm-rni/ (open source app)
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.1367&rep=rep1&type=pdf (paper)
http://www.ecsl.cs.sunysb.edu/tr/TR224.pdf (paper)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Sandboxie does it, but the usual way is through [File System Filter Drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx):

> A file system filter driver intercepts
>   requests targeted at a file system or
>   another file system filter driver. By
>   intercepting the request before it
>   reaches its intended target, the
>   filter driver can extend or replace
>   functionality provided by the original
>   target of the request.